# How to listen (not wait) for the results to be finished in parallel thread

Tags: java, okhttp

I have a code in my android app:

```
    homes=Get_HomeList(this, progressBar, view, mMap,MapsActivity.this);
    Log.v(TAG, "onMapReady: "+homes.size());
```

*Get_HomeList* is a function that fetches data from back end using asynchronous okhhttp call.

Inside this function I have onsuccessful method that is the place I have access to list of homes that has just been fetched.

However I need homes list outside of this function. but this line

```
Log.v(TAG, "onMapReady: "+homes.size());
```

gives me null for homes; I guess it is because it is running in parallel thread that has not seen home results yet.

Now my question is that how can handle this and be able to see fetched data outside *Get_HomList* function? Inside this function it looks like this:

```
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    try {
                        String responsedata = response.body().string();
                         homes= extractHomesUpdateMap(responsedata,mMap,mapsActivity);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {

             }
```

Is there a way that when loading is successful and *finished* I can pass the results outside of *Get_HomeList*?Or in General how we can deal with this cases?

Comment: You should do what you want to do inside that callback function.

Comment: That's what I am doing currently, but I need to do something which looks like cant do it this way. these two lines are in a mapActivity. I fetch the homes in the function and add markers on the map activity. However looks like to make markers click listener I need to implement some interface on map activity, which cant see the home list.